# How to start another build when a build succeeds in TFS 2013

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2013

In TFS 2013 I have Build A which compiles and runs unit tests.  I also have Build B which deploys to a dev server. How can I start build B when Build A succeeds in TFS 2013?

Comment: You would have to modify the process template to queue build B from build A, once you see the tests are completed successfully in A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a custom Workflow, Download the build Definition and then add the "Start Build"-Activity. Choose your build-workflow in the build-definition and voilà

Comment: Yeah I can't wait until this is built in.  FWIW I found the Community TFS Extensions that have a QueueBuild activity: https://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/documentation